# Matlab figure title w/ LaTeX not appearing?

Tags: matlab, latex, title, matlab-figure, interpreter

I am trying to label a plot I have using LaTeX. I have two problems: my title won't show up and I need to add text to a LaTeX expression. Ideally, I would like it to label my figure "f(x) for different values of n", but instead of "f(x)" I want this:

[image: LaTeX Expression]

How do I add the "for different values of n" portion to my LaTeX expression, and more importantly, why doesn't my title show up in the first place?

Here is my script:

```
x = linspace(0, 1, 100);
y1 = sin(pi*x);
y2 = sin(2*pi*x);
y3 = sin(4*pi*x);
hold on
plot(x,y1,'color',1/255*[255 20 147],'LineWidth',2);
plot(x,y2,'color',1/255*[0 238 118],'LineWidth',2);
plot(x,y3,'color',1/255*[0 238 238],'LineWidth',2);
xlabel('\theta','FontSize',15);
ylabel('$f_{s}(\theta)$','Interpreter','LaTex','FontSize',15);
title('$f_{s}(\theta)=\sin (n\theta\pi)$','Interpreter','LaTex',FontSize',18);
legend('n = 1', 'n = 2', 'n = 4','Location','best')
hold off
```

Comment: Is the missing `'` before `FontSize` in `title` also missing on your machine?

Comment: Just a comment: while `\theta` looks OK, I'd put that in Latex as well, for consistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, there is just an opening apostrophe before `FontSize` missing. Then, the title does show up. And to add the non-math text, just continue after the $ sign.

```
title('$f_{s}(\theta)=\sin (n\theta\pi)$  for different values of n','Interpreter','LaTex','FontSize',18);
```

Comment: What an embarrassing mistake! Thank you for helping me, nonetheless. Sometimes it takes another pair of eyes...

Comment: I am glad I could help.